SQL query to list rows from 1st table which does not appear in 2nd table

I have 2 tables : table1 and table2 where the common column is
"email". So, for each row gets inserted in table 1 with email:
test1@test.com, the same no of row gets inserted in table 2 as well
with email: test1@test.com. So, if there are 1000 records in table 1,
there should be 1000 records in table 2 as well. But now I am seeing 5
records less in table 2. So, I want to get those 5 rows from table 1
which are more. How can I get the 5 rows? I have tried several SQL
statements, but cannot get the result correctly. Can anyone help
please?

What I have tried:
SELECT email_id FROM table2 WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT c.id FROM `table1` c 
JOIN table2 l ON c.email=l.email_id) 


SELECT email_id FROM table2 t2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.email=t2.email) PS. ... ON c.email=l.email_id - this is strange, you compare email and its id.

not working still

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question Provide sample data according to #5 and #3.

IF by not working you mean no rows returned, have you tried the other way round (i.e. select * from table1 where not exists (select ... table2) - If still nothing returned, are you sure you have missing records in table2, and not duplicate records in table1? Does this return anything: SELECT email FROM Table1 GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1?

try this query with a left-join
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.email = t2.email_id WHERE t2.email_id IS NULL;


No rows are coming
